# Find cardinality of a set {$f \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}|f\le h$} where $h(n)=n+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, cardinals

On a set $\mathbb{N}$ is defined a partial order relation $f \le g \iff \forall{n\in\mathbb{N}} 
 f(n) \le g(n) $.

Also let $h: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ given by a formula $h(n)=n+1$.

Find cardinality of a set  {$f \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}   f\le h$}

I can't figure out how to find cardinality here and also what is $f$ in the end, is it just an arbitrary function?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: when computing the cardinality of a subset of something  of known infinite cardinality, always try showing it has that same cardinality. Sometimes it doesn't, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$, then $f\leq h$.
So $|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}| \leq |\{f\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} : f \leq h\}|$.

Comment: Thanks, but one thing is not clear for me :  how did you figure out that f: $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure I'm following you. What I meant was that all functions $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ are such that $f\leq h$, because $\{0,1\}\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $h(n)\geq 1$ for all $n$, and so $f(n)\leq h(n)$. So surely $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\subseteq\{f\in\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}:f\leq h\}$ and thus, $$2^{\aleph_0}=|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}|\leq|\{f\in\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}:f\leq h\}|.$$ Then I suppose you know that $|2^{\aleph_0}|=|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|$, giving the result.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the cardinality of the set of sequences
$$
S=\big\{(a_n): a_n\in\{0,1\}\big\}
$$
is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ and so is the cardinality of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$.

The set $A$ in the OP clearly satisfies
$$
|S|\le |A|\le |\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|
$$
Hence
$$
|A|=2^{\aleph_0}.
$$